# Wamp MyBB Forum Login failure

Tags: session, authentication, localhost, wamp, session-cookies

I have mybb forum on my website.
I am trying to make changes to my website.
I downloaded the contents of my website to localhost/wamp/www
Website works fine. When I try to login into mybb forum, it get redirected to login page again despite of the correct login.

Can someone tell me whats going wrong?

After debugging, I believe this could be a problem with localhost sessions.
Any help would be appreciated very much!

**I understood that the session variables are not getting stored, however, the session files are being created.**
What is the solution for wamp localhost sessions issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the cookie domain.

Login as forum admin. Goto Configuration --> settings --> general settings
Clear the field: Cookie Domain

In case your admin login fails or you are not able to select configuration after your login don't worry!

Open the file: /forum/inc/settings.php
Search for $settings['cookiedomain'] and set the field to empty string.

Now you can login into MyBB in your localhost!!